# How do I restructure this xml document based on proximity node siblings?

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri

I have an XML document outputted from a stock system which isn't structured particularly well:

```
<root>
    <StockSalesRec Type="SH">                               
        <Reference>A Supplier</Reference>     
        <StockNum></StockNum>                      
        <Description></Description>
        ...
    </StockSalesRec>                                        
    <StockSalesRec Type="  ">                               
        <Reference>12345</Reference>     
        <StockNum>00001</StockNum>                      
        <Description>Item description</Description>
        ...
    </StockSalesRec>                                        
    <StockSalesRec Type="  ">                               
        <Reference>67890</Reference>     
        <StockNum>00002</StockNum>                      
        <Description>Another description</Description>
        ...
    </StockSalesRec>
    ...
</root>
```

Each `<StockSalesRec Type=SH>` is a supplier and everything before the next `<StockSalesRec Type=SH>` is a product of that supplier. Before using this document I would like to restructure it so it looked something like:

```
<root>
    <supplier name="A Supplier">
        <product>
            <Reference>67890</Reference>     
            <StockNum>00002</StockNum>     
            <Description>Another description</Description>
        </product>
        ....
    </supplier>
    ....
</root>
```

How would I go about transforming the document this way? I've attempted using XSL for a solution, however got stuck pretty quickly. I'm currently learning Ruby lately so a solution using those would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done with a pure XSLT solution. I achieved it by first defining a key for every product (a **StockSalesRec** with a **Type** of '  ') for which the look-up is the **Reference** of the most recent preceding supplier record (a **StockSalesRec** with a **Type** of 'SH')

```
<xsl:key 
  name="Stock" 
  match="StockSalesRec[@Type='  ']" 
  use="(preceding-sibling::StockSalesRec[@Type='SH'])[last()]/Reference" />
```

You can then match on every supplier node like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="StockSalesRec[@Type='SH']" />
```

And then for each such supplier node, you can read through all the Product records using the key defined earlier

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('Stock', Reference)" />
```

Putting this altogether gives....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:key 
      name="Stock" 
      match="StockSalesRec[@Type='  ']" 
      use="(preceding-sibling::StockSalesRec[@Type='SH'])[last()]/Reference"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="StockSalesRec[@Type='SH']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="StockSalesRec[@Type='SH']">
      <supplier name="{Reference}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Stock', Reference)"/>
      </supplier>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="StockSalesRec[@Type='  ']">
      <product>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </product>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply this to your sample XML the output is as follows:

```
<root>
   <supplier name="A Supplier">
      <product>
         <Reference>12345</Reference>
         <StockNum>00001</StockNum>
         <Description>Item description</Description>
      </product>
      <product>
         <Reference>67890</Reference>
         <StockNum>00002</StockNum>
         <Description>Another description</Description>
      </product>
   </supplier>
</root>
```

Do note the use of the identity transform in creating the product node, allowing extra child elements to be added to the input XML without the need to change the XSLT.